# Finding Covariance using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, covariance

```
# dt---------indx_nm1-----indx_val1-------indx_nm2------indx_val2
2009-06-08----ABQI------1001.2------------ACNACTR----------300.05
2009-06-09----ABQI------1002.12 ----------ACNACTR----------341.19
2009-06-10----ABQI------1011.4------------ACNACTR----------382.93
2009-06-11----ABQI------1015.43 ----------ACNACTR----------362.63
```

I have a table that looks like ^  (but with hundreds of rows that dates from 2009 to 2013). Is there a way that I could calculate the covariance : [(`indx_val1` - avg(`indx_val1`)) * (`indx_val2` - avg(`indx_val2`)] divided by total number of rows for each value of `indx_val1` and `indx_val2` (loop through the entire table) and return just a simple value for cov(`ABQI`, `ACNACTR`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have aggregates operating over two different groups, you will need two different queries. The main one groups by `dt` to get your row values per date.  The other query has to perform `AVG()` and `COUNT()` aggregates across the *whole* rowset.

To use them both at the same time, you need to `JOIN` them together. But since there's no actual relation between the two queries, it is a cartesian product and we'll use a `CROSS JOIN`. Effectively, that joins *every* row of the main query with the single row retrieved by the aggregate query.  You can then perform the arithmetic in the `SELECT` list, using values from both:

So, building on the query from your earlier question:

```
SELECT 
 indxs.*,
 ((indx_val2 - indx_val2_avg) * (indx_val1 - indx_val1_avg)) / total_rows AS cv
FROM (
    SELECT 
      dt,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ABQI' THEN indx_nm ELSE NULL END) AS indx_nm1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ABQI' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val1,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ACNACTR' THEN indx_nm ELSE NULL END) AS indx_nm2,
      MAX(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ACNACTR' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val2
    FROM table1 a
    GROUP BY dt
  ) indxs 
  CROSS JOIN (
    /* Join against a query returning the AVG() and COUNT() across all rows */
    SELECT
      'ABQI' AS indx_nm1_aname,
      AVG(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ABQI' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val1_avg,
      'ACNACTR' AS indx_nm2_aname,
      AVG(CASE WHEN indx_nm = 'ACNACTR' THEN indx_val ELSE NULL END) AS indx_val2_avg,
      COUNT(*) AS total_rows
    FROM table1 b
    WHERE indx_nm IN ('ABQI','ACNACTR')
    /* And it is a cartesian product */
  ) aggs
WHERE
  indx_nm1 IS NOT NULL
  AND indx_nm2 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dt
```

Here's a demo, building on your earlier one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ec65/14

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Scalar-valued function to perform a covariance calculation on any two column table formatted to XML.

To Test: Compile the function then execute the Alpha Test

```
    CREATE Function [dbo].[Covariance](@XmlTwoValueSeries xml)
    returns float
    as
    Begin
    /*

    -- -----------
    -- ALPHA TEST
    -- -----------
    IF object_id('tempdb..#_201610101706') is not null DROP TABLE #_201610101706
    select *
    into #_201610101706
    from
    (
        select *
        from
        (
            SELECT '2016-01' Period, 1.24 col0, 2.20 col1
            union
            SELECT '2016-02' Period, 1.6 col0, 3.20 col1
            union
            SELECT '2016-03' Period, 1.0 col0, 2.77 col1
            union
            SELECT '2016-04' Period, 1.9 col0, 2.98 col1
        ) A
    ) A


    DECLARE @XmlTwoValueSeries xml  
    SET @XmlTwoValueSeries = (
    SELECT col0,col1 FROM #_201610101706
    FOR
    XML PATH('Output')
    )

    SELECT dbo.Covariance(@XmlTwoValueSeries) Covariance

    */
    declare @returnvalue numeric(20,10)

    set @returnvalue = 
    (
        SELECT  SUM((x - xAvg) *(y - yAvg)) / MAX(n) AS [COVAR(x,y)]
        from 
        (
            SELECT  1E * x x,
                    AVG(1E * x) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)) xAvg,
                    1E * y y,
                    AVG(1E * y) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)) yAvg,
                    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY (SELECT NULL)) n
            FROM    
            (
                SELECT 
                    e.c.value('(col0/text())[1]', 'float' ) x,
                    e.c.value('(col1/text())[1]', 'FLOAT' ) y
                FROM @XmlTwoValueSeries.nodes('Output') e(c)            
            ) A
        ) A
    )
    return @returnvalue
    end



    GO
```